# Table of contents - subsubsection numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I'm trying to get the subsubsection into the table of contents, but I can't get the numbering on the side of the subsubsection title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{toptesi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter 1}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't compile your document, even with the `.sty` that you provided, since `\documentclass` expects `toptesi.cls`. Can you please provide the appropriate setup to replicate your current issue?

Comment: @Werner I've edited the post with the .cls file

Comment: I see, you're using the standard [`toptesi`](//ctan.org/pkg/toptesi) bundle. In that regard, since it's on CTAN, there's actually no need to post the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toptesi` class uses within `\AtBeginDocument` `\frontmatter`, the latter restricting to `secnumdepth` to `2`. You need an explicit

`\mainmatter\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` after that.

```
\documentclass{toptesi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\chapter{chapter 1}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```